# IndexError: list index out of range - ошибка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вам дан массив целых чисел. Вы должны найти сумму целых чисел с четными индексами (0, 2, 4 ...). Затем умножьте это суммированное число и последний элемент массива вместе. Не забывайте, что первый элемент имеет индекс 0.

```
def checkio(array):
    res=0 

    for i  in  array:

                   if   array[i]%2==0 : #i+1<len(array) : 
                       res+=int(i)

                   else :
                       continue

                   if len(array)==0:
                       return res
    return res*array[-1]
```

Comment: Вы элементы массива используете как индексы для этого же массива.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать, например, так:

```
foo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
res = sum(foo[::2])*foo[-1] # 128
```

Вариант с функцией:

```
def sum_arr(arr):
    if len(arr) > 0:
        res = sum(arr[::2])*arr[-1]
        return res
    return 0

foo = [2]
bar = [1, 2, 3, 4]
baz = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
print(sum_arr(foo)) # 4
print(sum_arr(bar)) # 16
print(sum_arr(baz)) # 112
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def checkio(array):
    res = 0
    if len(array) == 0:
        return res

    for (index, value) in enumerate(array):
        if index % 2 == 0:
            res += value

    return res * array[-1]


def checkio(array):
    res = 0
    if len(array) == 0:
        return res

    for index in range(len(array)):
        if index % 2 == 0:
            res += array[index]

    return res * array[-1]
```